# Запись строк из файла

Tags: c++

Как записать в переменные `str1`,`str2` и т.д. типа `string` строки из файла, разделённые символом перехода на новую строку (при этом в них могут быть другие разделяющие символы, например, пробелы)?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string str = "aa aa\nbb bb\n";
    ofstream out("C:\\1.txt");
    out << str;
    out.close();

    string str1;
    string str2;
    ifstream in("C:\\1.txt");

    getline(in, str1);
    getline(in, str2);

    in.close();

    cout << str1 << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl;
}
```

или

```
vector<string> ArrStr;
string temp;
ifstream in("C:\\1.txt");
while(getline(in, temp))
    ArrStr.push_back(temp);
in.close();
for(int i = 0; i < (int)ArrStr.size(); ++i)
    cout << ArrStr[i] << endl;
```